# Derive summary statistic Grouped Data & Frequency Distribution Table

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, frequency, binning, point-estimation

I have the following data from the 2018 American Community Survey for a number of census block groups:

```
desc, estimate, , marginOfError
"Total:",839,"+/-",73
"Owner occupied:",729,"+/-",85
"Moved in 2017 or later",35,"+/-",32
"Moved in 2015 to 2016",51,"+/-",43
"Moved in 2010 to 2014",175,"+/-",64
"Moved in 2000 to 2009",264,"+/-",71
"Moved in 1990 to 1999",135,"+/-",53
"Moved in 1989 or earlier",69,"+/-",39
"Renter occupied:",110,"+/-",63
"Moved in 2017 or later",0,"+/-",12
"Moved in 2015 to 2016",41,"+/-",50
"Moved in 2010 to 2014",40,"+/-",38
"Moved in 2000 to 2009",20,"+/-",21
"Moved in 1990 to 1999",9,"+/-",14
"Moved in 1989 or earlier",0,"+/-",12
```

How do I approximate the median move in date for renters and owners?  (If possible, an illustration of the solution with `R` code would be welcome.)

Comment: Welcome to CV, Steve.  I took the liberty of modifying your question at the end so that people do not misperceive it as merely a request for programming help.  It will help readers to know what the US Census Bureau means by "Margin of Error:" The ACS is a complex ongoing survey.  The MoE is 1.645 times the Census estimate of standard errors of response.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my question.  For this question, let's assume that the margin of error represents a symmetric confidence interval in which the midpoint is the estimate.